# python tty.setraw Ctrl + C doesn't work (getch)

Tags: python, getch

This is my code.

```
def getch():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_Settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try: 
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        sys.stdin.flush()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("[Error] Abnormal program termination")
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd,termios.TCSADRAIN,old_settings)
    return ch
```

In this code, KeyboardInterrupt exception doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: After the edits, your code seems to be missing the `ch = sys.stdin.read(1)`, which is probably kind of important to this function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, when you set your TTY to raw mode—or, in particular, when you disable the [`termios`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) setting `ISIG`—you no longer get the corresponding behavior:

> ```
>   ISIG   When any of the characters INTR, QUIT, SUSP, or DSUSP are
>          received, generate the corresponding signal.
> ```

In other words, the character `INTR`, aka `^C` in most terminals, no longer generates a `SIGINT` signal, which [is what Python uses to raise a `KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html).

This is how full-screen programs like `emacs` can use `^C` as a control character instead of just quitting.

So, there are two options:

---

Instead of calling `setraw`, set the exact set of `termios` flags you want, making sure not to disable `ISIG`.

It's worth looking at the source to Python's [`tty.setraw`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/tty.py#L18) to see exactly what it does, to use as a baseline.

You could just do exactly the same thing without the `ISIG`. But really, you should read the docs to learn what each of these things means.

And make sure to `man termios` on your own system, don't search online; things are a bit different on Linux vs. macOS/*BSD, and there are minor differences even between versions of the same OS.

Even after reading the docs, and experimenting on your own, it may not be entirely clear what effect every setting has. [This article](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html) seems to do a decent job explaining things what goes into raw mode, and what each of the relevant flags actually means (although I only quickly skimmed it—and. again, you still need to read `man termios` for your platform).

---

Alternatively, you can just handle `^C` manually.

You're already reading a character at a time with `sys.stdin.read(1)`, so when someone hits `^C`, you're going to read a `'\x03'` character.

You can do whatever you want when that happens, including `raise KeyboardInterrupt`.

---

As a side note, if this is Python 3, you may want to read in binary mode:

```
ch = sys.stdin.buffer.raw.read(1)
sys.stdin.flush()
```

(Then you'll check against `b'\x03'` instead of `'\x03'`. of course.)

In text mode, you should get a whole character at a time, even if it's a multibyte character in UTF-8 (or whatever your locale is). Which *seems* simpler at first—but that can actually be misleading, because a single character can still be only part of a keystroke. For example, with most terminals, an up arrow sends 3 characters (`'\x1B[A'`)`, but`read(1)` will just give you the first one.

Comment: I wanted to know what I can get when I hit ^C. I used '\x03'. Thank you very much!!

Comment: You can only flush output streams. `sys.stdin.flush()` does nothing.